# How to get ZipArchive to not overwrite certain files and folders

Tags: php, zip

I would like to extract a zip folder to a location and to replace all files and folders except a few, how can I do this?

I currently do the following.

```
$backup = realpath('./backup/backup.zip');

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open("$backup", ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {

    die ('Could not open archive');

}

$zip->extractTo('minus/');

$zip->close();
```

How can I put conditions in for what files and folders should NOT be replaced? It would be great if some sort of loop could be used.

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this, I tested it and it works for me:

```
// make a list of all the files in the archive
$entries = array();
for ($idx = 0; $idx < $zip->numFiles; $idx++) {
    $entries[] = $zip->getNameIndex($idx);
}

// remove $entries for the files you don't want to overwrite

// only extract the remaining $entries
$zip->extractTo('minus/', $entries);
```

This solution is based on the **numFiles** property and the [**getNameIndex**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getnameindex.php) method, and it works even when the archive is structured into subfolders (the entries will look like /folder/subfolder/file.ext).
Also, the [extractTo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-extractto.php) method takes a second optional paramer that holds the list of files to be extracted.

Comment: Damn you Victor! You beat me to the punch :). +1 for a clean solution.

Comment: It has been a number of years since I did PHP, is it necessary to check "if ($zip->numFiles > 0)"?

Comment: @Andre: actually, not really, no, it's just a habit of mine to check before assuming something. I shortened the code a little bit.

Comment: that worked perfectly! I just needed to exclude 10 files out of 300 so I just removed elements from the array I did not need. Thank you! :)

Comment: I get where you are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract specific files from the archive (and you know what they are) then use the second parameter (entries).

```
 $zip->extractTo('minus/', array('file1.ext', 'newfile2.xml'));
```

If you want to extract all the files that do not exist, then you can try one of the following:

```
$files = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    // if $filename not in destination / or whatever the logic is then
        $files[] = $filename;
}
$zip->extractTo($path, $files);      
$zip->close();
```

You can also use `$zip->getStream( $filename )` to read a stream that you then write to the destination file.